# Set default browser from within app

Tags: android, intentfilter

I'm developing an app that we will put on Android tablets on be used by employees in the field. We want to lock down internet access as much as possible to minimize data usage (so that the employees can't go streaming Netflix movies or something and driving up our data usage). As part of that effort, I'd like to have http(s)?:// links open up in a custom activity I made. Now, I can easily do that by registering the activity with an intent filter on the http/https schemas, but I'd prefer not to have the user have to choose between browsers when opening a link, and I don't want my activity to become the default activity for every link (there may be situations in which the user should be using the Android browser).

Is there a way to set up my activity as the http handler...but only for links launched from my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to set up my activity as the http handler...but only for links launched from my app?

If the links are from your app, just use `startActivity()` with an `Intent` identifying your activity, rather than some generic `Intent` like `ACTION_VIEW`.

If your issue is that you are displaying the Web content in a `WebView` and links clicked *there* lead to the browser, use `setWebViewClient()` along with a `WebViewClient` implementation that handles `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`.

Comment: I had wanted to use this as a last resort, as what I'm hoping to do would be simpler--for instance, if I `Linkify` text, it would open in my WebView activity instead of the browser. Now, maybe there's a way to Linkify with a custom intent--to be honest, I haven't looked too deeply into Linkify--but chances are I'd end up having to roll my own link.

Comment: @thayes: "for instance, if I Linkify text, it would open in my WebView activity instead of the browser" -- ah. "maybe there's a way to Linkify with a custom intent" -- in theory, you could use a `Linkify.TransformFilter` to create an `Intent` pointing to your stuff, then use `toUri()` on the `Intent` to get a `Uri` that you would use with the filter. I haven't tried this, though. If that fails, push come to shove, use your own custom scheme with the filter (e.g., `thayes://`) and set up your activity to watch for those URLs. Custom schemes are to be avoided, though, where possible.